# Failed Payment Redirect in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, redirect, payment-gateway

When a customer has an order canceled due to their credit card being declined it seems all extensions redirect customers back to the cart page and not the actual payment page in the checkout.

Is this because the message manager cannot display messages to the customer? Or is that a way of redirect the customer back to /checkout/#payment and display the relevant error messages?